# How to Send A UDP packet via public IP through NAT?

Tags: java, c, udp, nat

I have a UDP server running on my private network.I have a device which is beyond NAT which sends UDP packets to my server through public IP. I am able to receive the UDP packets, parse them and I can view the pay load, src and dest port. Now I need to send an ACK message to that device so I have captured the ip and port numbers and sending a UDP packet to it. But I could not able to view any UDP packets in that device.

My question is as my Device is beyond NAT the IP address and port number I am getting is NAT's or the actual device's ?

How to send the UDP packet to that device through NAT ?

Comment: IMHO, the question is off-topic here. It fits better in http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching

Answer (score 1):

> My question is as my Device is beyond NAT the IP address and port number I am getting is NAT's or the actual device's ?

The IP and Port you identify from the packet are those which the NAT created a mapping for the client. In simple words, it is the IP and Port of the NAT to which the device is connected.

> How to send the UDP packet to that device through NAT ?

You need to reply on the IP and port detected by the server from the packet it received from client.
More clearly you need to implement **UDP Holepunching**.

I guess you should first understand the networking issues regarding connection to devices working under a NAT. Various **RFC**s are available for **NAT Traversal** and **UDP Punching**.

Here are some sources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4787

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5128